# Can't create EOMOdel in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, webobjects

I am trying to create my first project according to the instructions of the wiki. I created a new project and then installed the ant tools, as instructed.

Then I tried to create a new eomodel using File->New->Other...->eomodel.

First pop-up is fine, but the second doesn't show any adapters and won't let me click finish either with no adapter. It does not give out any error code, though, simply ignores the click. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what versions of Eclipse and WOLips? How did you install WOLips? (what URL)

I have Eclipse (Mars) with WOLips from the update site:

https://jenkins.wocommunity.org/view/WOLips/job/WOLips44/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/temp/dist/

you Installed all the Webobjects and Wonder frameworks yes?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.

I have Eclipse 3.8.1 with WOLips 2.7.20140223.48. I installed WOLips manually (the complete zip from the Jenkins site) because the "Install New Software..." option in Eclipse doesn't seem to be working. It times out, possibly because of proxy problems. I count 41 plug-ins for WOLips in the Plug-in window. I also installed WOLips Ant Tools.

Comment: see now that I was lacking some installation steps. In particular running WOInstaller.jar. I tried to run it but I get a "connection time out" error. 

$ sudo java -jar WOInstaller.jar 5.4.3 $HOME/workspace/WebObjects543/Versions/WebObjects543.

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

I realized I didn't have the last build and changed to 4.4, but still same error.

P.S. I am running on Debian and most of the documentation I see is for Mac.

Comment: Solved, thank you. I could finally install everything rollbacking to the original condition and it worked.